# how to debug a cron job and how i can see the logs?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, logging, cron

I have an web-app with a servlet on app-engine

and a cron job that calls that servlet

I see the cron returns status 200, but I dont see the expected change in the DB

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MatchingServlet.class.getName());


@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    String credential = config.getInitParameter("credential");
    String databaseUrl = config.getInitParameter("databaseUrl");

    System.out.println("Credential file : " + credential);
    logger.info("Credential file : " + credential);
```

I have tried to add logging, but how can i see them in the google-cloud console

[image]

cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/match</url>
        <description>find buddies to all users</description>
        <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>

my methods:


@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("in matching-servlet doGet");
    doPost(req, resp);
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("in matching-servlet doPost");
    firebase.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Comment: Show more of your code, both of the cron job, and of the servlet, e.g. `doGet()` or `doPost()` methods, that should be called by the cron job.

Comment: I added, though i'm looking for the logs basically

Comment: If you are using the App Engine project template, inside the file logging.properties the main level is configured as WARNING. You need to modify it to INFO to show the INFO log messages

Comment: that solved the issue. How about logs in the callback "onDataChange" how come i cannot see them? is there a way to see them?